# How can I install Gitosis to my server without sudo access?

Tags: git, sudo, gitosis

I am trying to follow [these commands](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst).

I managed install Git to my server without sudo access. However, I need sudo access to add a new user: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553279/how-can-i-run-sudo-commands-without-sudo-access). It seems that Gitosis is very hard to install without sudo access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see [the page](http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2008/09/installing_gito.html) for the answer.